# ExtJs4 - chart on click event?

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, charts, extjs4

How can I add a click event to a chart in Extjs4.
I achieved this with the following in ExtJs3 but does not work in ExtJs4 -

```
    chart.on('itemclick', function(evtObject) {
        ....
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemmouseup`

[Ref](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.chart.series.Series)

Comment: Thanks amol. I wouldn't have found that.